# C# - Human readable serialization alternatives to BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, serialization

I have an object serialized via

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("filename");
formatter.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, the_object);
writer.Close();
```

Is there a way to view it in a more understandable form, for example, in json? Thanks

Comment: Look at JSON.NET which has a JSON-based serializer/deserializer.

Comment: Or the XMLSerializer native to .NET

Answer (score 2):

Using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(the_object);
```

---

To deserialize it, you can either specify the object's type via generics:

```
YourEntity deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourEntity>(serialized);
```

Or you can take advantage of [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) (Requires C# 4.0 or newer):

```
dynamic deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialized);
```

Comment: Problem with Json.Net is that the type is now always safe. For example Int vs. Long. So I had to use BinaryFormatter for those values. Isn't there an alternative solution that is typesafe and can be easily exchanged with BinaryFormatter (just for debugging purposes)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the only way to "view" a serialized object in a particular format is to serialize it into that form first.  You are not going to be able to take a binary-serialized object and look at it in JSON, unless you want to write a ton of code to transform a binary object to JSON.  But that would be a complete waste of time.

If the data is already serialized in binary, then deserialize it into class objects and then re-serialize it into JSON or XML.  Then you can open those files and understand what the contents are.