# c# save dictionary with <string,List<string>> in .dat with Binaryformatter (or something else)

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, chatbot

```
     FileStream fs = new FileStream("Answears.dat", FileMode.Create);
     Dictionary<string, List<string>> chats = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

     BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
     public void Start()
    {

                chats = (Dictionary<string, List<String>>) formatter.Deserialize(fs); //here is a error 
                fs.Close();

    }
```

do you now any other option to save the dictionary(and also later load again) in a file. ^^

thanks for you help

Paul :)

Comment: See [BinaryFormatter alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3512776/3744182) or [C# - Human readable serialization alternatives to BinaryFormatter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33265104/3744182).  Related: [What are the deficiencies of the built-in BinaryFormatter based .Net serialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/703073/3744182).

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), independent from assembly version changes and results in a readable text...

```
File.WriteAllText(filename, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourDict));
```

Later, you can load it as

```
var yourDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,List<string>>>(File.ReadAllText(filename));
```